# Encrypted boot partition: advantage of encrypted boot partition

Tags: grub, uefi, encryption

I would like to understand more about the Linux boot process and how encryption works for the boot partition. I have a few questions.

- I know that a UEFI system must have a ESP partition, which can be mounted either in `/boot/efi` or `/efi`. The ESP partition contains the bootloader and the kernel. On my Endeavour OS system I also have `/boot`, which only contains the Intel microcode. What I understood is that the system first loads the bootloader (in my case systemd-boot) which then loads the selected kernel. So, with my current configuration and in general in UEFI system, what is the purpose of `/boot` if a separate `/efi` exists?
- Then, I would like to encrypt my system and I was reading the Arch Wiki guide "Encrypted boot partition (GRUB)". In this case, what is left unencrypted is GRUB and the ESP. For a UEFI system, what is the advantage of this approach? What is now encrypted that would be so in a "normal" configuration? What is still inside the ESP?
- I am also trying to learn what is EFISTUB and how it works. What I have understood is that a bootloader is not used and unified kernel images are put inside the ESP. In this case is `/boot` still necessary?

Comment: "a ESP partition [...] mounted either in /boot/efi or /efi" ... It can be mounted anywhere as long as you tell your bootloader where it is. "unified kernel images are put inside the ESP. In this case is /boot still necessary?" ... That's what I use and I just mount my ESP on /boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an UEFI system, its firmware will expect to find at least the first part of whatever you want booted in ESP. That first part could be the UEFI version of GRUB, some other bootloader like `systemd-boot`, or a unified kernel image with EFISTUB.

(If you use Secure Boot, and the firmware won't let you change the built-in Secure Boot keys, you'll have to use a Secure Boot shim (`shimx64.efi`) as the first step, before whatever else you wish to use. If you can configure the firmware to use your own Secure Boot keys and you sign the bootloader & the kernel yourself with your own keys, you won't need the shim.)

Unless you have some very special UEFI firmware, the ESP can never be *encrypted*, or else the firmware cannot make any sense of it. But with Secure Boot, any executable code in ESP must be *signed*, so any significant tampering of the ESP will stop the system from booting (assuming the implementation is correct).

Where the kernel needs to be depends on what you use as a bootloader. If you use GRUB, the kernel can be on any filesystem GRUB can understand (LVM or classic partition; encrypted or not). With `systemd-boot`, I understand the kernel needs to be on the ESP; and with EFISTUB, the firmware is told to read an appropriately prepared kernel file directly, so it obviously needs to be on the ESP.

GRUB can do some forms of disk encryption, but it might not have support for the newest disk encryption algorithms yet. Also, if you want to use a security device like a smart card or a Yubikey as a disk encryption key, then you'll probably need an initramfs file that will contain the necessary infrastructure for accessing that security device and presenting any necessary prompts to the user. Normally an initramfs file goes to the same place the kernel goes to.

If you place your kernel (and initramfs if needed) to the ESP, you probably won't need a separate `/boot` at all (or your ESP can be mounted at `/boot`, as commented by @muru). The same is true if you use GRUB and it can directly read your kernel (and initramfs if needed) from your root filesystem, i.e. if want encryption and are satisfied with the encryption options provided by GRUB.

But the "absolute maximum security at the price of some convenience" option could be something like:

- the ESP contains only the Secure Boot shim (if needed) and GRUB, both protected by Secure Boot signatures
- GRUB will prompt a passphrase to unlock an encrypted `/boot`, and will read the kernel & initramfs from there (encrypted, but maybe not quite the best possible encryption)
- initramfs contains the infrastructure to request a smart card/Yubikey/etc. which will contain the key(s) for unlocking any other filesystems. These can now use the hardware security device and/or the latest & greatest encryption algorithms supported by the kernel. If the system contains a TPM chip, you could even use its PCR registers to verify that the firmware or any of the previous components of the boot process haven't been tampered with.